# How to add cache contexts to a region

Tags: 8, caching, theming

How can I add cache contexts to a region. I have been able to do this to my blocks but have noticed that parts of the region remain cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a cache context to a region the same way as to any other page element:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['region'] == 'myregion') {
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';
  }
}
```

But this is probably not what you want, because regions are not cached. Usually the blocks inside a region are cached and the complete page which contains the regions. The cache context of the region will only have an effect on higher level elements, not downwards.